# Received memory warning. Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, memory

I developer iOS application but when i try to run in iPhone then its crashed when select image.

```
Show this error:  Received memory warning. Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died
```

I run it in iPad but not issue but faced issue in iPhone only.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error could occur when your code uses a large amount of memory. The reason it does not occur on iPad confirms this, because iPads generally have more memory (both physical and virtual). Please try to debug your code to remove excessive memory usage.